# Different number of mapper running with MR+hcatalog v/s Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

I facing hard time to figures out, why i am getting different number of mapper when i run query  using hive query and when i run the MR on same hive table using hcatalog.

```
Difference is significant for same input volume
With Hive Query : 913 mapper
With MR+hcatalog : 3106 mapper
```

I am using RC file as storage format on table, which i am accessing .
and also I didn't applied any tweak in input split size at both places(hive or MR)

Any clicks, why this is happening, i have tried set mapred.max.split.size=536870912 while running MR, it is also giving me effect to reduce the number of mapper.

Comment: Pig combines files together on the fly (mappers get multiple files in) which leads to fewer mappers. This is useful when there are many small files. Hive might do the same.

Comment: You are right , i have also done analysis on this , it is happening due to implementation of CombineFileInputFormat which understand mapred.max.split.size. Is there any ways i implement CombineFileInputFormat  with RCFIle in  MR+hcatalog

Comment: How does MR+hcatalog calculate the mapper. I was looking into HCatSplit but have not been able to figure out. Is it based on pure block size like vanilla MR ?

Comment: yes , it looks like i tried it , it splitting exactly on same logic what you achieve using Plain MR.